# div position:absolute with 100% width

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a `div` with `position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;` properties. 
The problem is this div is taking **only** the `width` of the content inside but I want this div to fill the whole page `width` even if the content is not.

If I add `width:100%` then the div becomes `100%` of total browser width and it brings a scroll at the bottom.

Is there any way to fill the rest width of the page with `position:absolute`?

CSS for the div I want to fill the rest of the width

```
.container{position:absolute;top:50px;left;100px;}
```

Here it is on http://jsfiddle.net/BxLy6/ for your inspection.

Please suggest how I can fill the rest of the page with `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
bottom: 0;
```

That should do it.
http://jsfiddle.net/BxLy6/4/

Comment: Though you (may be I could not explained it) misunderstood me but you are right. Adding `right:0` does the trick and even on IE6 :) thanks..